# How to create an entity which, when stepped on, only switches a boolean value once while rendering?

Tags: loops, libgdx, boolean-logic, tiled

I am programming a simple Libgdx game utilizing TiledMap. I am attempting to create a pressure plate that, when stepped on by the player character, only switches an "activated" boolean value once. Currently, the boolean value is constantly switching within the rendering function I am drawing the pressure plate.

I am assuming this is relatively simple, just cannot wrap my head around it.

Here is the PressurePlate class as it stands:

```
public class PressurePlate extends GameTrigger {
     private boolean activation; // whether the pressure plate is "on" or "off"

     public PressurePlate (Texture img, Vector2 initialPos) {
         super ("PressurePlate", initialPos, img, true);
     }




     public boolean isCurrentlyUsed (ArrayList <Entity> entities) { 

         for (Entity e : entities)
         {
             if (e.getIntPositionX() == this.getIntPositionX() && e.getIntPositionY() == this.getIntPositionY())
             {
                 return true;
             }
         }
    
         return false;
     }


     public boolean isActivated () {
         return this.activation;
     }

     public void setIsActivated (boolean isActivated) {
         this.activation = isActivated;
     }

 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That means setIsActivated is called many times with different values. You should check where it is called, write logs in setIsActivated to record the parameter when it is called.
If you want help from here, you need to post all codes that call setIsActivated, else nobody can help.